# Qt5 no polish characters after reading from QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, qt5, qnetworkreply

I need to get data from this url https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/lasta.xml. The problem is that `response` contains broken polish characters (????? instead of śćąęó).

My console and GUI is fully capable of showing polish characters and only this one `content` string is broken.

I have no idea what to do with this. I'm using CLion on Linux.

```cpp
#include "DataDownloader.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QMessageBox>

std::string DataDownloader::downloadData() const
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(this->url)));
    QEventLoop event;
    connect(response, SIGNAL(finished()), &event, SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();

    std::string content = QString(response->readAll()).toStdString();

    return content;
}
```

Edit:
Actually other sites that contain polish signs work just fine. But still, I have to make it work with the one I provided above

Edit 2:
Seems like this xml is encoded in ISO-8859-2. This explains the issue but I still don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: _Seems like this xml is encoded in ISO-8859-2._ How underhanded... (I'm a fan of UTF-8 everywhere.) You might consider an even more general solution where you extract the XML encoding somehow from response to use it as variable in `QTextCodec::codecForName()` (although I've not the slightest idea how to achieve this). ;-)

Comment: If it's XML with encoding information in it, best is not to convert at all, but pass as QByteArray and let the XML parser handle the encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works.

```cpp
std::string DataDownloader::downloadData() const
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(this->url)));
    QEventLoop event;
    connect(response, SIGNAL(finished()), &event, SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();

    QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO-8859-2");
    QTextDecoder decoder{codec};

    return decoder.toUnicode(response->readAll()).toStdString();
}
```